# How to allow only argument values greater than zero for any method?

Tags: c#, range, divide-by-zero

I try to limitate my methods so that some input arguments only allow numbers greater than zero. I thought about creating my own class, but generating an object for each method call seems to be ineffective to me. Silly example method:

```
public class Whatever
{
  public uint Num1 { get; }
  public double Num2 { get; }

  public Whatever (uint num1, double num2) {
    Num1 = num1;
    Num2 = num2;
  }

  public double SillyDivide() {
    var result1 = Num1 / Num2;
    var result2 = Num2 / Num1;
    return result1 + result2;
  }
}
```

Obviously, I try to avoid division by zero, by only allowing number higher than zero, or not equal to zero. What is the best way to implement this?

I found a Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419194/what-is-the-best-way-of-adding-a-greater-than-0-validator-on-the-client-side-usi) and tried to implement it, but it did not make any difference:

```
public class Whatever
{
  [Required]
  [Range(1, uint.MaxValue)]
  public uint Num1 { get; }

  [Required]
  [Range(double.Epsilon, double.MaxValue)]
  public double Num2 { get; }

  public Whatever (uint num1, double num2) {
    Num1 = num1;
    Num2 = num2;
  }

  public double SillyDivide() {
    var result1 = Num1 / Num2;
    var result2 = Num2 / Num1;
    return result1 + result2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just the attributes on their own won't do anything.  You need code *somewhere* that checks the value against the attributes.  There are a lot of frameworks that build this in, like MVC model validation.  But you didn't provide much context outside of this class.

Comment: You just need to validate your inputs. Throw an exception if a number isn't in an acceptable range for example.

Comment: `if (num1 < 1) throw new ArgumentException("num1 must be >= 1");` Similar idea for `num2`.

Comment: You can't really check whether floating point numbers are 0 or not in order to avoid a possible exception. What you should do is catch divide by 0 errors, and other potential errors from a division attempt. For all integer types you can check for 0 of course.